# What does speaking in third person denote?

Tags: abnormal-psychology

Is speaking (or preferring to speak, even if not actually doing it) about oneself in third person a symptom of any specific mental condition?

I can remember a person in an IRC role playing chat room who preferred to speak this way. But apart from this specific case, I am also asking in a broader context.

Comment: Upvoted because it is an interesting question. My non-expert opinion: I think it would hard to design a study that pinned such behavior on a "specific mental condition". For instance, it could easily be viewed as an effect of narcissism (cf. the royal "we", or "your king commands it") or a sign of dissociative disorder ("The other one told me to do it"), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking about oneself in the third person is known as [illeism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illeism).

It is not a symptom of any mental condition listed in the DSM. As Wikipedia notes, it is sometimes used in speech and literature for stylistic reasons.

Comment: I was asking about the cases when a person generally feels like using it, excluding intentional uses such as in literature, etc.